# HTML ASP Table cells shifting left when they are empty

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET 3.0+, and have a table as follows:

```
 <asp:Table ID="metadataTable" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" CellSpacing="5">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell BorderWidth="3" ID="tcProperties1" ><asp:PlaceHolder ID="Properties1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell BorderWidth="3" ID="tcProperties2" ><asp:PlaceHolder ID="Properties2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell BorderWidth="3" ID="tcProperties3" ><asp:PlaceHolder ID="Properties3" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell BorderWidth="3" ID="tcTree1" VerticalAlign="Top"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="Tree1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell BorderWidth="3" ID="tcTree2" VerticalAlign="Top"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="Tree2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell BorderWidth="3" ID="tcTree3" VerticalAlign="Top"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="Tree3" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
 </asp:Table>
```

The problem is that the placeholders are sometimes intentionally empty.  For this I call:

```
tcProperties2.Visible = false;
tcTree1.Visible = false;
tcTree3.Visible = false;
```

and the cells are shifting left.  i.e. when I want:

```
[Cell 0,0]            [Cell 2,0]
           [Cell 1,1]
```

where cell 0,1 1,0 and 2,1 have no Controls, and I get the following instead:

```
[Cell 0,0] [Cell 2,0]
[Cell 1,1]
```

Is there any way to keep them spaced out without using the obvious &nbsp hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your code, either by including it at an external/embedded CSS stylesheet, or by adding an inline style:

```
table {
    empty-cells: show;
}
```

Comment: I added that inline: <asp:Table style="empty-cells:show" ID="metadataTable" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" CellSpacing="5"> and still getting the cells shifted to the left :(

Comment: @Tizz Can you provide a link to your generated HTML (source)?

Comment: I wish I could, this is internal development (not personal code)

Comment: I guess that you're using IE? Add `&nbsp;` before every closing tag: `&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>`. This adds a space at the end of each cell, causing the cell to be "not empty".

Comment: Yep IE.  Im guessing that is the only way.  Thanks!